# How to loop a list until all items in a list are matched with user input then stop the loop with Bingo message for bingo game in python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

`my_list` items should be matched with user input when matched all numbers a message should show bingo and loop should be stopped

```py
print('...............Welcome to BINGO.................')

my_list = ["15", "22", "35", "48", "80", "55", "12", "36", "45", "26"]
    
i = str(input("press ENTER to play BiNgO!"))
     
for i in range(10):
    number_input = input("enter a number between 1 to 80")

    if number_input in my_list:           
        my_list.remove(number_input)
        print("hurray! this number is matched")
    else:
        print("oops! not matched")
```

Comment: replace `for i in range(10)` with `while my_list` (which checks whether the list has any elements in it)?

Comment: hi thank u for your help i am going to check it now,....thanks again

Comment: can you help me with : what should i do if i want to write a code for stop the loop when all numbers are matched? any help will give me support, as i am totally new for coding thanks

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: thanks, Michael, I will definitely go through all chapters you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_list = ["15", "22", "35", "48", "80", "55", "12", "36", "45", "26"]

i = str(input("press ENTER to play BiNgO!"))

for i in range(10):

   number_input = input("enter a number between 1 to 80")

   if number_input in my_list:
       my_list.remove(number_input)
       print("hurray! this number is matched")
       break

   else:
       print("oops! not matched")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We need to use `while` loop when we don't know the number of iterations to be made.
The `while` loop should terminate when `my_list` is empty.

So the code should be:

```py
print('...............Welcome to BINGO.................')

my_list = ["15", "22", "35", "48", "80", "55", "12", "36", "45", "26"]
    
i = input("press ENTER to play BiNgO!")
     
while my_list != []:
    number_input = input("enter a number between 1 to 80")

    if number_input in my_list:           
        my_list.remove(number_input)
        print("hurray! this number is matched")
    else:
        print("oops! not matched")
```